# Facebook SDK For Android Problems

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, sdk

I am developing an app which needs to login via facebook and I am having a few problems.

I have read the facebook sdk page a few times but it is very confusing, I saw tutorials for older versions of the SDK and it used to be much easier to understand their code.

I have been looking at example codes for their SDK for nearly 5 hours and I still don't understand what funcions are used to login (seen like 6 different examples and they all seem completely different) plus I also copy pasted some codes in order to try them out with the android sdk emulator and they all seem to crash at start...

Can anyone make a small post of the basic functions related to the facebook login and their uses?

Thanks

Comment: Haven't you tried sample example they have given?

Comment: The examples they provide are not working for the android emulator the sdk provides (it might be because the emulator doesn't have facebook app). (This is something I want to know, because I currently don't have a android in hand to know if this can be the problem)

Plus the examples all use different methods, so I don't really know which can be used to login. 
(Is it possible that the login is done through their button by creating a (LoginButton) and nothing else?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for you to Login to facebook, you can use the `

```
Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback(){

    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception){
        //here check to see if session is not null, isopened and isopening 
        //do other important stuff here
    }
```

});

Then pass in the desired arguments. These will include a callback method.

If an active session is non-existent, the SDK (using the boolean parameter (true) on Session) will pop up a Login window for your users to login and do whatever you need to do inside a call method which you must override.
`